# Breaking retain cycle with strong/weak self

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I've read posts about strong/weak `self` to break retain cycles but I am still confused as to how they work. I understand the use of `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self` to create a weak reference to self but I am confused about strong reference. As I understand it, the strong reference is so that there is a strong reference to `self` so that it doesn't get deallocated before the end of the block right? So why is it necessary to have `__strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf`? Doesn't this end up pointing to the self object anyway? So why not just `strongSelf = self`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any non-weak object that you reference inside the block will result in an implicit retain on that object, as the block is being created.  Not executed, but created.

If you initialised the inner strongSelf directly from self, you will retain the value of self and potentially cause a retain cycle.

On the other hand, if you initialise it from weakSelf, you will *not* retain the value of weakSelf.

This is the reason for the two-step.  The outer code copies the value of self into weakSelf, but ARC does not add a retain because it is __weak().

The block "creation" copies the value of weakSelf (or at least, manages to makes its value available at execution time).  You can't see where it copied it to, but it did.

At block "execution" time, the block copies the "value of weakSelf" (which will be nil if self has been dealloc'ed in the mean time) into strongSelf which ARC then applies a retain to.  Thus, for the duration of the block, the object referenced by strongSelf will remain alive, if it was alive to begin with.  If you had only relied on weakSelf, it could go nil at any time during the execution of the block.

Note that weak/strong pattern is belt-and-braces - many examples actually rely on the fact that the weakSelf will go nil, and the block will silently become a collection of no-ops (messages to nil).

Retain cycles typically only occur if (a) you keep a reference to the block in a self.property or (b) you hand the block off to some other object (notification manager, etc), and tell that other object to forget it in your dealloc; in both cases your dealloc will never be called while the block is alive.

When people say "the way to do this stuff is with the weak/strong pattern", they are assuming the worst possible scenario.

Comment: Ooh so `weakSelf = self` assigns `weakSelf` a copy of `self`? That seems a little odd, I thought it pointed to the original `self`. is that because of the block or is that how variable assignment works?

Comment: @user1813076 - No, `weakSelf = self` does _not_ assign `weakSelf` to a copy of `self`. The `weakSelf` is a pointer to `self`, a pointer that it set to `nil` when `self` is deallocated.

Comment: This isn't helped along by the sneaky nature of closures and variable scope. It is the actual variable "weakSelf" which is essentially copied, not the object that it points to.

Comment: Consider that weakSelf, strongSelf and self are all variables that *point* to a single object.  When you copy that pointer into another variable, ARC steps in and "increments the retain count" on the referenced object, unless the variable is __weak() in which case it arranges for the variable to be nilled if the referenced object is dealloc'd.  Blocks secretly copy all the outer-scope variable that they reference.  Not the objects, just the variables.  (Note: this is ignoring __block which is a different game again)

Comment: when using instance in block of NotificationCenter call, why we need to go for _weak? It won't create any retain cycle right?

Comment: It is difficult to answer this since Apple have not-so-helpfully introduced two different things, both called "the notifcation centre".  If you are talking about NSNotificationCenter then the documentation says your block is COPIED, not RETAINED.  The copy will have the same retention policy on whatever self/weakself variable you employed.  So, yes, I believe a notification block would be strong enough to keep your object alive unless you do the weakself/self shuffle.

Answer (score 13):

The pattern is:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[manager someAsynchronousMethodWithCompletionHandler:^{
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        ...
    }
}];
```

The idea is that the completion handler block will have only a weak reference to `self`, so that if `self` is released before the completion block is called, then it will safely be deallocated because the block has no strong reference to it. (A common example is when a view controller initiates some asynchronous network request to update a view, if the view controller is dismissed before the network request finishes, there's no point on hanging onto the view controller instance for a view that is long gone.)

But, this `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern also ensures that if the opposite happens, that the completion block has started and encounters the `strongSelf` line before `self` is released, the block will ensure that `self` is retained for the duration of the running of that block (i.e. it can't get deallocated half way through the running of the completion block, even if this is running on a different thread). This has a number of potential benefits (ranging from object integrity to the elimination of race conditions). Sometimes you don't actually need the `strongSelf` half of the "`weakSelf`/`strongSelf` dance", but it's an invaluable tool when needed.

If, however, you had a line inside the block that said, `typeof(self) strongSelf = self` (instead of `weakSelf`), the mere presence of `self` in the righthand side of that statement would result in the block maintaining a strong reference to `self` up front, entirely defeating the purpose of using `weakSelf` in the first place.

Comment: I don't think you have the pattern right.  The inner assignment of strongSelf from self should be from weakself.

Comment: It should be `typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;` inside that block.

Comment: But doesn't `strongSelf = weakSelf` make `strongSelf` point to `self`? Or is there something slightly different occurring

Comment: @user1813076 If `self` hasn't be released yet,`strongSelf = weakSelf` _will_ set `strongSelf` to `self`. But if `self` has been released by the time it hits that line of code, then `weakSelf` will be `nil` and thus `strongSelf` will also be set to `nil`.

Comment: So if `self` hasn't been released then `strongSelf` will be set to `self` then isn't that essentially the same as `strongSelf = self`? And wouldn't that cause a retain cycle so that `strongSelf` is never released along with `self`?

Comment: @user1813076 - No, it's not the same and that's why you don't have a strong reference cycle. If a block references `self` directly, the block establishes a strong reference to `self` as soon as the block is instantiated (which could easily result in strong reference cycle). But if you reference `weakSelf`, the existence of the block does not establish strong reference to `self`. And if you have a line that says `strongSelf = weakSelf`, that does _not_ establish a strong reference when the block is instantiated, but rather _only when that line of code is run._ Hence no strong reference cycle.

Answer (score 1):

There are correct answers, but I really do not know, whether they are answers to your Q. They explain the problem of retain cycles with blocks using self in general, but your Q was:

> So why not just strongSelf = self?

The answer to this Q:

If one would do this, `self` would be a part of the block's closure and always be retained. The whole story with weak self would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self - We use this just before block,

**This is just pointer to self, no retain cycle started**

-- Retain will be done if and only if block will execute

--> If we make it strong then it will start retain cycle and will consume memory, even if we don't call block

Answer (score 0):

One point must be cleared that you are not using weak/strong pattern to avoid retain cycle! Whether you use a strong reference to self or to weakself, you are not avoiding retain cycle. Retain cycle is broken by the reference variable scope! When it reached the end of the scope, the reference variable is dealloced. The weak/strong pattern is just a protection mechanism that prevent you make a strong reference to nil, since before the block is created and run, self maybe dealloced.